# make: *** No rule to make target `Device-Debug'. Stop.

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx

i am using QNX momentics for blackberry development. The problem is whenever i download any sample code  and run it on Simulator. then error comes to me.

When i clean the project it give me Error

```
**** Clean-only build of configuration Simulator-Debug for project list ****

make -j4 clean 
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

And when Build the project it gives me

```
**** Build of configuration Simulator-Debug for project list ****

make -j4 Device-Debug 
make: *** No rule to make target `Device-Debug'.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

These error are not allowing me to run any sample code. please can any one tell me how can i solve this problem . I have set the target as a Simulator-Debug .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your x86/Makefile is not getting generated.

Can you open a regular command window and prep the shell using the bbndk-env.bat file from your BBNDK installation dir, then type the following from the top level of your demo project?  (Replace YOURPROJECT.pro with whatever your .pro file actually is)

```
qmake -spec unsupported/blackberry-x86-qcc -o x86/Makefile YOURPROJECT.pro CONFIG+="simulator debug_and_release"
```

Does the x86/Makefile get generated?  Any errors?

Can you post the Makefile for the demo you are using?

Comment: Sir I solve my problem . the mistake which i was doing was when ever i import project i was selecting "Existing Code as Blackberry C/C++ Makefile Project" instead of "Existing Projects into Workspace" Which solve my problem . Yes you were right my Makefile was changing and cause problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I noticed that the Makefiles of blackberry projects are the sames except the QMAKE_TARGET tag. So I simply copied them from project directory and (project dir)/translations and changed QMAKE_TARGET to the proper project name.
It built without any issue.

I would say it happened because of the git directory config when it was pushed.